# Cant map json to POJO

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My controller looks like given below.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/addenquiry", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public Response<Enquiry> addEnquiry(@RequestBody Enquiry enquiry,HttpSession session) {
    Response<Enquiry> response = new Response<Enquiry>();


@Component
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Enquiry {

    private String enqId;

    //Getters and setters which are public
```

However when I pass the Json using

```
{
    "enqId;":"875421ekhrfkejhsjdf"
}
```

It is not getting mapped , and prints the null.

Comment: Other classes are able to map but not this one

Comment: Why do you have `;` in the end of the property name of your json the `{ "enqId;"`?

Comment: Without ; also it not working

Comment: @StanislavL : Could you see any reason for this not happening.

Answer (score 3):

You have to delete the `@Component` annotation in your `Enquiry` class. If you add a Spring annotation like `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service` you specify that the class will be a spring bean. In default the bean will be a singleton bean and just lives ones in the context.

In your case you want to post a new Enquiry Object by every request. Behind the scenes spring and jackson will do that for you. Without the `@Component` annotation it will be a normal POJO and does not exist in the spring context.

Site note: If you really want that `Enquiry` is in the spring context you can leave `@Component` annotation and add the scope `prototype`.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Enquiry {}
```

This specify that spring creates a new instance everytime you ask for it.